# Maths operators

Tags: java, android, if-statement

I have this method which will generate a random maths expression solve it and output the answer to a variable:

```
public int Nov2()
{
    char[] ops = new char[] {'+', '-', '*', '/'};
    int i = rand.nextInt(4-0) + 0;
    char op1 = ops[i];

    int novnum1 = rand.nextInt(101-1) + 1;

    int novnum2 = rand.nextInt(101-1) + 1;

    int nov2result = 0;

    switch(op1) {
        case '+': nov2result = novnum1 + novnum2; break;
        case '-': nov2result = novnum1 - novnum2; break;
        case '*': nov2result = novnum1 * novnum2; break;
        case '/': nov2result = novnum1 / novnum2; break;
    }

    String nov2Exp = novnum1 + " " + op1 + " " + novnum2 + " = ";

    Nov2resstor = nov2result;

    setContentView(R.layout.gameview);

    TextView display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.exp);

    display.setText(nov2Exp);

    return nov2result;
}
```

How would i use the same sort of thing for expressions with more than two terms without having to write really complex if statements like this in my next method:

```
public int Eas3()
{
    char[] ops = new char[] {'+', '-', '*', '/'};
    int i = rand.nextInt(4-0) + 0;
    char op1 = ops[i];
    i = rand.nextInt(4-0) + 0;
    char op2 = ops[i];

    int easnum1 = rand.nextInt(101-1) + 1;

    int easnum2 = rand.nextInt(101-1) + 1;

    int easnum3 = rand.nextInt(101-1) + 1;

    int eas3result = 0;


    if (op1 == '+' && op2 == '+')
    {
        eas3result = ((easnum1 + easnum2) + easnum3);
    }
    else if (op1 == '+' && op2 == '-')
    {
        eas3result = ((easnum1 + easnum2) - easnum3);
    }
    else if (op1 == '+' && op2 == '*')
    {
        eas3result = ((easnum1 + easnum2) * easnum3);
    }
    else if (op1 == '+' && op2 == '-')
    {
        eas3result = ((easnum1 + easnum2) - easnum3);
    } 
.../
```

I have methods which do this for 2,3,4,5 and 6 so my if statements would become very large using this method.

Any ideas?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern

Answer (score 2):

Yes, another way to do it is to write Command objects:

```
public interface Command<V> {
    V execute(Object ... args); 
}
```

You'll write an object that implements this interface:

```
public class AdditionCommand implements Command<Double> {
    public Double execute(Object ... args) {
        Double x = (Double)args[0];
        Double y = (Double)args[1];
        return x+y;    
    }
}
```

Now you can look up in a Map using the operator:

```
Map<String, Command> opsLookup = new HashMap<String, Command>() {{
   opsLookup.put("+", new AddCommand<Number>());
   opsLookup.put("-", new SubtractCommand<Number>());
}};
```

No need for a switch.

Comment: Would you be able to show me how to implement that for my example? Im not quite following what you've put there

Comment: Im sorry i'm still not understnading it. What exactly does object ... args mean?

Comment: This is where you come in.  You have to do the barest amount of digging.  Variable parameters have been part of Java for almost eight years: http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2004/04/19/varargs.html

Answer (score 2):

you can use the built-in Javascript engine.

```
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;
import javax.script.ScriptEngine;

public class Test 
{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
  {
       ScriptEngineManager mgr = new ScriptEngineManager();
        ScriptEngine engine = mgr.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
        String foo = "40+2";
        System.out.println(engine.eval(foo));
    } 
}
```

Comment: Btw, if the values are taken from an EditText or something, just be careful to check and validate what has been entered.

Comment: javax.script isnt a recognised import for me

Comment: How can i add the ScriptEngine to android?

Comment: Try this instead:
http://jeval.sourceforge.net/
It seems it has the evaluate method which evaluates any expression:
http://jeval.sourceforge.net/docs/api/net/sourceforge/jeval/Evaluator.html#evaluate(java.lang.String)

Comment: It doesn't seem to like that either, i can find no way to get ScriptEngine into Android.

Comment: No no , i was saying you should download the JEval class, or package whatever it is, from the first link in my previous comment and add it to your project. And you'll be able to use the evaluate method which this class/package provides. That should solve your problems. :)

Comment: once ive added it to my project would i need to import it? If so i can't see how to.

Comment: Well, i'm guessing you've set the classes you just downloaded in a package inside your project, no? If the name of the package in which all these classes are is, let's say, "jeval", then you just type "import jeval.*" wherever you want to use the methods inside that package. Or...have i understood the question wrong ?

Comment: Well i googled some instructions on how to add a jar to my android project and i added them as it said into a new folder which i then added to the build path. I just have no idea what the import line would look like and i cant find one anywhere

Comment: Ahh I've got it imported now i just have to figure out how to use it.

Comment: If you're using Eclipse, as i presume you are...After you did the build thing, try writing some code and create a new instance of the class from JEval, as you know Eclipse underlines it with a red line and if you take your mouse over that, you can select the import line which you want and eclipse adds it automatically. OR, just create a new package in your src folder, only add the class files that were in the downloaded zip and then just import the package. Try it some more, you'll figure it out eventually :)

Comment: Great...if it's usefull, don't forget to accept the answer :D It would be the first one ever for me. lol

Answer (score 2):

[Check out this MathEval class I found online](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/5724095/Android%20Apps/MathEval.txt) It will evaluate a String that represents an equation for you.

```
mySolver = new MathEval();
double answer = mySolver.evaluate(equation);
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is called the [composite pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern). You define an abstract `Expression` base class and derive it.

The classes must implement an `evaluate()` method which returns the result.

One sub class will be the constant which return it's value, another one would be a binary expression like plus, minus, etc. The `evaluate()` method will add/subtract/etc the result of the evaluated sub-expressions.

You can then build arbitrary expressions out of other expressions and then evaluate it without using one if condition.

Answer (score 1):

How about using recursion:

```
int num(int numberOfOperands, int current){
    if(numberOfOperands<=0) return current;
    switch(rand.nextInt(4)){
        case 0: return num(numberOfOperands-1, current + (rand.nextInt(100)+1)); break;
        case 1: return num(numberOfOperands-1, current - (rand.nextInt(100)+1)); break;
        case 2: return num(numberOfOperands-1, current * (rand.nextInt(100)+1)); break;
        case 3: return num(numberOfOperands-1, current / (rand.nextInt(100)+1)); break;
    }

}

int num(int numberOfOperands) throws Exception{
    if(numberOfOperands <=0) 
        throw new Exception("invalid number of operands: "+numberOfOperands);
    return num(numberOfOperands, rand.nextInt(100)+1);
}
```

This would, of course, ignore precedence of operations.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a string with the variables you are using like this:

```
String temp = "(" + easnum1 + op1 + easnum2 + ")" + op2 + easnum3;
```

after that you can use the ScriptEngineManager class to use javascript as the engine so you can use the eval method.

```
ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("js");        
Object result = engine.eval(temp);
```

this method does the calculations and returns the result.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I would use an array for the values easnum[], an array for the operands op[] and an array with intermediate values.
Something along the following lines

```
  for(...)
  {
     if(op[i]=='+') easintermediat[i+1] = easintermediate[i] + easnum[i]
     ...
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you've got *n* operations on *n+1* numbers, and you do the first one, then you're left with *n-1* operations on *n* numbers. You can use this as the basis for a loop that will process any number of items easily.

```
int operate(int[] numbers, int[] operations) {
  if (numbers.length < 1 || numbers.length != operations.length + 1) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException();
  }
  int result = numbers[0];  
  for (int i = 0; i < operations.length; ++i) {
    result = operate(operations[i], result, numbers[i+1]);
    // where operate() is your switch statement
  }
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public int Eas3()
{

    char[] ops = new char[] {'+', '-', '*', '/'};
    int i = rand.nextInt(4-0) + 0;
    char op1 = ops[i];
    i = rand.nextInt(4-0) + 0;
    char op2 = ops[i];

    int easnum1 = rand.nextInt(101-1) + 1;
    int easnum2 = rand.nextInt(101-1) + 1;
    int easnum3 = rand.nextInt(101-1) + 1;
    int eas3result = 0;
    if (op1 == '+')
    {
         switch(op2) 
         {
               case '+': eas3result=((easnum1 + easnum2) + easnum3); break;
               case '-': eas3result=((easnum1 - easnum2) - easnum3); break;
               case '*': eas3result=((easnum1 * easnum2) * easnum3); break;
               case '/': eas3result=((easnum1 / easnum2) / easnum3); break;        
         }
    }

..../

}
```

or even you can put outer IF in SWITCH like the following

```
public int Eas3()
{

    char[] ops = new char[] {'+', '-', '*', '/'};
    int i = rand.nextInt(4-0) + 0;
    char op1 = ops[i];
    i = rand.nextInt(4-0) + 0;
    char op2 = ops[i];

    int easnum1 = rand.nextInt(101-1) + 1;
    int easnum2 = rand.nextInt(101-1) + 1;
    int easnum3 = rand.nextInt(101-1) + 1;
    int eas3result = 0;
    int tempResult=0;
    switch(op1)
    {
         case '+': tempResult=(easnum1 + easnum2); break;
         case '-': tempResult=(easnum1 + easnum2) ; break;
         case '*': tempResult=(easnum1 + easnum2) ; break;
         case '/': tempResult=(easnum1 + easnum2) ; break;        
    }    
   switch(op2) 
     {
         case '+': eas3result=(tempResult + easnum3); break;
         case '-': eas3result=(tempResult - easnum3); break;
         case '*': eas3result=(tempResult * easnum3); break;
         case '/': eas3result=(tempResult / easnum3); break;        
     }
```

}